# Отработка вложенного цикла определённое количество раз при выполнении внешнего цикла один раз

Tags: php

Есть один цикл и второй, который вложен в первый. Необходимо, чтобы первый цикл один раз отработал, а второй цикл (вложенный) отработал по условию некоторое количество раз (например, 20). Но вместо этого либо оба цикла выполняются по одному разу, либо что-то подобное.

```
$domains = array('domain.ru','yo.com');
$arr = file('keys.txt');  // тут ключи вытаскиваем в массив
$usekeyword = 20; // На сколько делить ключи
$mas100 = array_chunk($arr, $usekeyword); // делим
$cdomain = count($domains); // считаем кол-во доменов
$d = 0;// отвечает за первый цикл 
$i = 1; // - отвечает за второй цикл
while ($d < $cdomain) { // самый главный цикл   
    while ($i <= $usekeyword) { // вложенный цикл
        echo $mas100[$d][$i] .  $domains[$d]  ; // получаем ключи и выводим вместе 
        //c доменами     
        $i++;
        # continue(1); // тут пытался и break и continue - без толку
    }
    $d++;
}
```

Comment: Если вам нужно, чтобы внешний цикл отработал **строго один раз**, то может вам и не нужен цикл?

Comment: У внешнего цикла тоже есть условие. Оно тоже будет меняться.

Comment: у вас, мне кажется, проблемы с логикой - чанк поделит на группы по 20, а не на 20 частей, а цикл вы хотите делать 20 раз. Это верно только. если в файлу 400 строк всегда. Может, внутренний цикл нужно делать по длине полученного массива?

Comment: Такой вариант рассматривался,но был переделан. Не зря там группы. Одна группа - один домен (или выполнение главного цикла)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вам нужно сбрасывать счётчик вашего вложенного цикла:

```
while ($d < $cdomain) { 
    $i = 1; // сброс счетчика!
    while ($i <= $usekeyword) {
```

иначе после первого прохода вложенный цикл никогда не будет выполнятся, т.к. условие `$i <= $usekeyword` сразу же будет нарушено.